# Apache CXF - Very slow performance on first call

Tags: performance, soap, cxf

I am using Apache CXF 3.2.7 on my web application for a SOAP web service client.
I generated the client through wsdl2java and I reuse the port for the call.
The strange behaviour is that on first call (and only on the first call) of the client it requests a lot of time to send the SOAP request. It takes 20-30 seconds !!!

```
  private void init() {

    if (port != null)
        return;
    // initialize the client

   }

   public void call() {
     init();

     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     ResponseObject wsResponse = port.getSomething(...);
     long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis()- start;

   }
```

Analizyng some logs I noticed that the port.getSomething() requires a lot time BEFORE sending the SOAP request.
The following calls are very very fast.

Googling around I read some articles about this issue and it seems a CXF "feature" but I don't understand if there is a workaround

PS: In my opinion it is a sort of "bug" because 20-30 seconds are "ridicolous" time for modern hardware ...

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Have you used a profiling tool to see where the time is lost? It's most probably not in CXF but on a lower layer or on server side (maybe some initialization). If you provide a reproducable sample, I'll also take a look...

Comment: For some strange reasons the problem disappears with no modification ...